# How to increase uTorrent's download speed?

Tags: download, connection, utorrent

I would like to increase my download speed of uTorrent. 
In this moment I'm downloading a Torrent at 450KB/s but my connection can reach 1.5MB/s. How can I male uTorrent use all my broadband connection?

Comment: Have you double-checked in settings if there is no download limit or limit for maximum connections (peers) defined? Although good point from Steven (would not be surprised if this Q was for farming, lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few factors in download speed :-

One is your connection, as you say yours is capable of 1.5MB/s;

Another is congestion, how much other stuff is also being downloaded at the time on that connection.

Another, and in your case more relevant, is the availability of upload for the torrent in question. If you only have 1 seeder with an *upload* limit of 450KB/s, the you won't get any faster. More seeders with more upload capability will allow you to download faster.